# Android Studio no option to change Gradle JDK path

Tags: flutter, android-studio, gradle

I have been trying to install Flutter and everything went smoothly until I launched the debugger and got an error stating, you need java 11 or higher to build your app with this version of gradle.

I went to preferences -> build, execution, deployment -> gradle

but there's no option for updating the path. How do I fix this?

[image]

I expected to see Gradle JDK path under Gradle projects, but there is no such option present whatsoever.

Comment: To fix this issue,  you have to installed the latest version of Java on your machine. check the `version` by `java -version`  and　[download latest version](https://www.java.com/en/download/) and adjust the path in your machine.

Comment: I have java 15 installed, but gradle isn't able to detect that. So, I think there might be some problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

The JDK pane isn't shown for Flutter apps on the root level.
To set the JDK, do the following:

1. Go to File > Project Structure.
2. Under Platform Settings, find "SDKs"
3. Choose `Embedded JDK`
4. Locate "JDK home path" and tap the folder icon.
5. Choose the desired JDK version OR tap "Select JDK home from disk" and locate it in finder, usually in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` for MacOS.

More related issue fixing steps at https://stackoverflow.com/a/76172515/840958