# While running the app , i am getting this exception

Tags: android

An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_242-release). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
java.lang.AssertionError: annotationType(): unrecognized Attribute name MODULE (class com.sun.tools.javac.util.UnsharedNameTable$NameImpl)
at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.error(Assert.java:133)

Comment: Have you checked this ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72441688/5696047