# Flutter application not working due to Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make a flutter application but I constantly get this error :

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
     You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`
```

I followed this question : [Android Studio Error "Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66980512/android-studio-error-android-gradle-plugin-requires-java-11-to-run-you-are-cur)

and this was the output :

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2022-02-08 09:58:38 UTC
Revision:     f0d9291c04b90b59445041eaa75b2ee744162586

Kotlin:       1.5.31
Groovy:       3.0.9
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          13.0.7 (Private Build 13.0.7+5-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04)
OS:           Linux 5.4.0-125-generic amd64
```

JVM points to 13.0.7. What can be issue and how can it be resolved? Thankyou

Comment: No. Becausse in that case JVM points to 1.8. Mine points to 13.0.7. I dont know why

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using?

Answer (score 1):

In your Android Studio IDE, go to ~

Preferences → Build, Execution, Deployment → Build Tools → Gradle → *Gradle JDK
[image]
and choose the appropriate JDK version and apply. Try to take the embedded JDK as that would be IDE version appropriate. After this sync project and run.

Comment: i did go to this location but it only opens uptil checkbox where its written generate *.iml files --- Gradel. Below part is not visible from Gradle Products. No idea why

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot for better understanding??

Answer (score 1):

For me this error came up after downloading JDK 11 and upgrading flutter.

First start by following the instructions at https://stackoverflow.com/a/76172567/840958.

If that doesn't work, here's what fixed this error for me:

1. Download JDK v11 from https://www.openlogic.com/openjdk-downloads and install is.
   Then make sure you set these configurations:

- In `android/build.gradle` under `buildscript` set

> ```
> buildscript {
>     ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
>     ...
> }
> ```

- Also in `android/build.gradle`, update the dependencies to

> ```
> dependencies {
>     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
>     classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
>     ...
> }
> ```

- In `android/app/build.gradle` update the dependencies to

> ```
> dependencies {
>     implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
>     ...
> }
> ```

- Also in `android/app/build.gradle`, under `android` update the `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` as such:

> ```
> android {
>     compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
>     ...
> }
> ```

> ```
> defaultConfig {
>     targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
>     ...
> }
> ```

- Also in `android/app/build.gradle`, add or update:

> ```
> compileOptions {
>     sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
>     targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
>     ...
> }
> ```

and

> ```
> kotlinOptions {
>     jvmTarget = '1.8'
> }
> ```

2. Set the JDK gradle will use in the Flutter app by following the instructions at https://stackoverflow.com/a/76172567/840958.
3. In `build.gradle` I had code under 'repositories' that was binding to an earlier version of gradle, which I had to remove:

   ```
   allprojects {
       repositories {
         ...
         tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
            javaCompiler = javaToolchains.compilerFor {
               languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(8)
            }
          }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Remove all references to repositories that are using older versions of gradle:

`jcenter()`

and

`maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }`

5. From `gradle.properties` remove (if it exists):

`android.enableR8=true`

6. From `app/build.gradle` remove (if it exists):

`useProguard true`

and

`apply plugin: 'io.fabric'`

Answer (score 0):

Check your version of Android Studio and update to Dolphin (2021.3.x).

There are plenty of answers to this question out there that simply ask you to point to the right SDK.  None of them appreciate that in some 4.x versions of Android Studio, you can be pointing to the right SDK, but Android Studio keeps pointing to the v1.8, even if you have a version >11 installed and selected in:

- Project Structure, or
- Preferences

It's possible that: C:*\java -version --> Results in jre/jvm >11, your 'flutter doctor -v' still says: jre/jvm-1.8.

If you don't see the above screen posted by GeekyChick in settings (i.e., "it's a location that only opens up a checkbox where its written generate *.iml files"), than you probably have Android Studio v4.x, rather than a 2021.x or greater.

Upgrade your Android Studio to Dolphin, and re-follow the instructions to choose the right SDK in Project Structure (not Settings).