# An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_402). Please file a bug against the Java compiler

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile-development

I am working with an older android app(Not allowed to upgrade). Target SDK version 1.8. And I am getting this error after using `Java corretto-1.8.0_402`.

```
An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_402). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
java.lang.AssertionError: annotationType(): unrecognized Attribute name MODULE (class com.sun.tools.javac.util.UnsharedNameTable$NameImpl)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.error(Assert.java:133)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations.annotationType(TypeAnnotations.java:231)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.separateAnnotationsKinds(TypeAnnotations.java:294)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.visitMethodDef(TypeAnnotations.java:1066)
```

This is my Gradle.

```
    
    compileSdkVersion 33
    buildToolsVersion "33.0.0"
    defaultConfig {

        
        minSdkVersion 19
        
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 20114
        //versionName "2.1.9"
        versionName "2.2.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
```

I tried [Solution from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69258509/an-exception-has-occurred-in-the-compiler-1-8-0-301) .They didn't work.

Comment: Well.. did you file a bug?

Comment: `Target SDK version 1.8. ` ???

Comment: If you have any questions then please ask.

Comment: @blackapps upgrading everything in project structure worked.