# Flutter Build Error: Execution failed for task ':cloud_firestore:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting the following error message when I try to build my flutter app for android (using `flutter build apk`):

```
An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_242-release). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
java.lang.AssertionError: annotationType(): unrecognized Attribute name MODULE (class com.sun.tools.javac.util.UnsharedNameTable$NameImpl)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.error(Assert.java:133)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations.annotationType(TypeAnnotations.java:231)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.separateAnnotationsKinds(TypeAnnotations.java:294)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.visitVarDef(TypeAnnotations.java:1164)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCVariableDecl.accept(JCTree.java:852)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.scan(TypeAnnotations.java:275)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:57)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.visitClassDef(TypeAnnotations.java:1042)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCClassDecl.accept(JCTree.java:693)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.scan(TypeAnnotations.java:275)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$1.run(TypeAnnotations.java:127)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.flush(Annotate.java:152)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.enterDone(Annotate.java:129)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:512)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:471)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.enterTrees(JavaCompiler.java:982)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:857)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:129)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:138)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessingCompileTask.call(AnnotationProcessingCompileTask.java:93)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ResourceCleaningCompilationTask.call(ResourceCleaningCompilationTask.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:100)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:38)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.execute(AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.execute(AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.java:37)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilerFactory$2.execute(IncrementalCompilerFactory.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilerFactory$2.execute(IncrementalCompilerFactory.java:97)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.execute(IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.java:60)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.execute(IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler$2.call(CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler$2.call(CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.execute(CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:158)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:126)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AndroidJavaCompile.compile(AndroidJavaCompile.kt:237)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:103)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskInputsTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskInputsTaskAction.java:47)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.execute(AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.java:25)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$5.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:476)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:461)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:444)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:93)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:237)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$0(ExecuteStep.java:32)
        at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:32)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:58)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:39)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:31)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:208)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:70)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:32)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
        at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:76)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:69)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:140)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':cloud_firestore:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 3s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                      64.3s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

I am using version `3.1.0` of the package `cloud_firestore`:

```yaml
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.0
```

The following is my `android/build.grade`:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'  // Google Services plugin

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and my `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    throw new GradleException("versionCode not found. Define flutter.versionCode in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    throw new GradleException("versionName not found. Define flutter.versionName in the local.properties file.")
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  // Google Services plugin
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.revoteeninccompany.revoteen"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 31


        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName


        multiDexEnabled true

    }
        signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.7'
}
```

I have freshly downloaded the `google-services.json` file and replaced the one in the `android/app` directory, and the `cloud_firestore` package should be on the latest version. I am using flutter version 2.2.2.

How can I resolve this error? Is it an issue with the version of the package, the version of flutter I am using, or something else? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you make the required changes in `app/build.gradle' as well?

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad I just edited my question to include `app/build.gradle` as well. I am pretty sure I followed the steps correctly.

Comment: Hi, can you see if any of these links help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68344424/unrecognized-attribute-name-module-class-com-sun-tools-javac-util-sharednametab, https://exerror.com/unrecognized-attribute-name-module-class-com-sun-tools-javac-util-sharednametablenameimpl/ .

Comment: may be because apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' appear twice

Comment: @mariofrancois I removed the second instance of that line in `android/app/build.gradle` but it still failed.

Comment: Have you tried flutter clean? Can you debug the project or the problem is just in building the APK?

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad I have tried `flutter clean`, and it is just the build process. It looks like it's failing when trying to compile a dependency (`cloud_firestore`), not any of my project code.

Comment: Hi, I thin this issue is related to this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70352925/9102464
At least this one solved my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally solved this problem, thanks to [R.Schaefer's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69960033/flutter-build-error-execution-failed-for-task-cloud-firestorecompilereleasej?noredirect=1#comment124757989_69960033). I needed to upgrade the gradle and kotlin versions by following the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70352925/5923147).

When I tried building after these steps, I got the error

```
No version of NDK matched the requested version 21.0.6113669. Versions available locally: 21.3.6528147
```

I solved this by adding the line `ndkVersion "21.3.6528147"` (just copy pasted the version the output said was available) in the `android{}` block of my `android/app/build.gradle` file. After this, the app built and everything worked properly.