# Android API level 31 error - Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, kotlin, android-12

> ```
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> 2022-02-01T10:52:30.421+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
> 2022-02-01T10:52:30.421+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went
> ```
>
> wrong:
> 2022-02-01T10:52:30.421+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution
> failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> 2022-02-01T10:52:30.421+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > A failure
> occurred while executing
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
> 2022-02-01T10:52:30.421+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    >
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
> 2022-02-01T10:52:30.421+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
> 2022-02-01T10:52:30.421+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
> 2022-02-01T10:52:30.421+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  Run with
> --scan to get full insights.
> 2022-02-01T10:52:30.421+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
> 2022-02-01T10:52:30.421+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception
> is:
> 2022-02-01T10:52:30.422+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task
> ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
>
> ```
> Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException:
> ```
>
> A failure occurred while executing
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution.run(KaptWithoutKotlincTask.kt:179)
> Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: annotationType(): unrecognized Attribute name MODULE (class
> com.sun.tools.javac.util.SharedNameTable$NameImpl)
> 2022-02-01T10:52:30.435+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]     at
> com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.error(Assert.java:133)
>
> ```
>     enter code here
> ```

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68344424/unrecognized-attribute-name-module-class-com-sun-tools-javac-util-sharednametab

Answer (score 4):

You would need to update your gradle jdk to 11

`settings/preferences > Build,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle`