# Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Unable to load Maven meta-data from

Tags: android, gradle, sdk, build.gradle, targetsdkversion

I updated my targetSDKVersion and compileSdkVersion from 30 to 32, but now when I'm running the app, app:KaptDebugKotlin is failing. I used the debug-option to get more details and I'm receiving this error:

[image]

My **build.gradle (module)** file:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 32
buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.eschbachit.petrolinemobile"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 32
    versionCode 1628
    versionName "2.3.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        debuggable true
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
buildFeatures {
    dataBinding true
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
    mavenCentral()
}
```

And this is my **build.gradle (project)** file:

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.20-M1'
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
}
ext {
    compiler_version = '3.1.3'
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$compiler_version"
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.3.0'

}
```

My distributionURL is: **distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-bin.zip**

I tried different solutions from other answers but nothing worked for me

**EDIT**: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69250502/15352563 solved my issue! If anybody have the same issue, this might help