# java.lang.AssertionError: annotationType(): unrecognized Attribute name MODULE (class com.sun.tools.javac.util.SharedNameTable$NameImpl)

Tags: android, gradlew, assemble

[same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68344424/unrecognized-attribute-name-module-class-com-sun-tools-javac-util-sharednametab), but exec `gradlew clean assemble` in terminal still throw error.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: annotationType(): unrecognized Attribute name MODULE (class com.sun.tools.javac.util.SharedNameTable$NameImpl)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.error(Assert.java:133)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations.annotationType(TypeAnnotations.java:231)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.separateAnnotationsKinds(TypeAnnotations.java:294)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.visitMethodDef(TypeAnnotations.java:1066)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodDecl.accept(JCTree.java:778)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.scan(TypeAnnotations.java:275)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:57)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.visitClassDef(TypeAnnotations.java:1042)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCClassDecl.accept(JCTree.java:693)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.scan(TypeAnnotations.java:275)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$1.run(TypeAnnotations.java:127)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.flush(Annotate.java:152)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.enterDone(Annotate.java:129)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:512)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:471)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.enterTrees(JavaCompiler.java:982)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:83)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:31)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.Kapt.kapt(Kapt.kt:47)
        ... 25 more
```

My environment:

- compileSdkVersion 31
- classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"
- classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10"
- distributionUrl=gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
- Gradle JDK:Android Studio default JDK(version 11.0.10)
- Android Studio: Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2

Any advise? Thanks in advance.