# Target SDK 33 this app isn't available for your device because older version of android

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, targetsdkversion

All users see this error when attempting to install my app from Google Play store.

I have the error message " This app isn't available for your device because it was made for an older version of Android."

We have an old android app that recently was updated to target API level 33. However, the app cannot be installed from Play Store on an Android device due to "This app isn't available for your device because it was made for an older version of Android", despite double checking the target API level of our bundle in the Play Console.

This is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'jacoco-android'
apply plugin: 'com.palantir.jacoco-coverage'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
     
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.compb.comp.arlcomp"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 40
        versionName "3.3.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}


jacocoAndroidUnitTestReport {
    excludes += ['**/application/**' ,'**/opentock/**',
                 '**/utils/**']
}

task moveReport(type: Copy) {
    if (file("${buildDir}/jacoco").exists()) {
        from("${buildDir}/jacoco/")
        include 'testDebugUnitTest.exec'
        destinationDir file("${rootProject.buildDir}/jacoco/")
        rename 'testDebugUnitTest.exec', "${project.name}.exec"
        ant.echo(message: "$name")
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.opentok.android:opentok-android-sdk:2.23.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.4.0'
    implementation 'com.tapadoo.android:alerter:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.sdsmdg.tastytoast:tastytoast:0.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    implementation 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.0'

    implementation 'com.github.uin3566:AllAngleExpandableButton:v1.2.0'

    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'

    // Animations
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.8.0'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'

    // Swipe
    implementation 'com.nikhilpanju.recyclerviewenhanced:recyclerviewenhanced:1.1.0'

    // Calendar
    implementation ("com.github.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:2.0.1") {
        exclude group: 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp', module: 'threetenabp'
    }
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.1.1'

    // Mockito
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.27.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

and this is my Android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.compb.comp.arlcomp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<!--    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />-->

    <application
        android:name=".application.MyAplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_app2"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:targetapi="28"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup">

        <receiver
            android:name=".utils.AlarmNotificationReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />


        <activity
            android:name=".presentacion.splash.view.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:exported="true"

            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".presentacion.login.view.ActivityLogin"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_act_inicio"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <activity
            android:name=".presentacion.home.view.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <activity
            android:name=".presentacion.calendar.view.CalendarActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarCalendar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".presentacion.home.view.HomeActivity" />

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".presentacion.webview.ActivityWebView"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <activity
            android:name=".presentacion.videocall.view.ActHomeVideoCall"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
            android:resizeableActivity="true"
            android:configChanges="screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|orientation"
            tools:targetApi="n"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please verify if you new app version is compatible with API level. Release > Reach and devices > Device catalog https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7353455?hl=en

If everything is looking good then you can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75819408/6890699 that indicates this is due to a Google Play bug.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).