# This app isn’t available for your device because it was made from an older version of android

Tags: android, google-play, android-11, motorola, target-sdk

I have published app in playstore with minSdkVersion = 21 and targetSdkVersion = 33, one of my client Motorola Moto G31, with Android 11 device get below error in playstore
"This app isn’t available for your device because it was made from an older version of android"
but in other users with andorid 11 they can install the app with no issues

any one have any idea about this issue

Answer (score 0):

In Client Phone try to update Google Play Store to new version with active gmail account.

To Update Goto Google PlayStore App -> Settings -> About -> Play Store Version -> click "update Play store"

Also Update System Apps like "SystemWebview" App, "Google" App.

if it wont help try to clear cache of Google Play store from Setting App.

Answer (score 0):

This one solution might help if you didn't try it before
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/thread/207103832?hl=en&msgid=207111741

Answer (score 0):

Please verify if you new app version is compatible with API level 33. Release > Reach and devices > Device catalog https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7353455?hl=en

Is your app already published but with an older api version (api level 29 or lower)?

If so, it may be a bug in Google play, which is describe in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75819408/6890699