# Google play Internal Testing not working due to older API level in production track

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Google play indicates "This app isn't available for your device because it was made for an older version of Android" while trying to do Internal Testing for an apk with latest sdk release

[Google Play Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOLme.png)

Gradle config

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.interconnect.app"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 25
        versionName "0.55.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Google play shows that Android 12+ are compatible with our apk [Google Play compatible list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1f7B.png)

Is there anything else im missing?

This answer indicates is some kind of bug in Google Play Internal Testing. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75819408/6890699