# Upgrading Java version from 8 to 11 to build apk with jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, android-gradle-plugin

We use a Jenkins job to build apks.
In order to upgrade gradle to version 7.2, it is required to upgrade Java to version 11.

After installing java 11's openjdk on the jenkins server, the jenkins job fails for some modules with the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':common:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':common:androidJdkImage'.
   > Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: /opt/android/platforms/android-30/core-for-system-modules.jar.
         > jlink executable /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/jlink does not exist.
```

Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Suggest having a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66449161/how-to-upgrade-an-android-project-to-java-11

Comment: thanks, even though it is related to Android Studio, this answer is really helpful:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/69043157/2068732

Answer (score 3):

`jlink` was indeed missing in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/`

Reinstalling openjdk11 fixed this:

- sudo apt autoremove openjdk-11-jdk-headless
- sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk-headless