# React Native : Task :app:installDebug FAILED Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0

Tags: android, react-native

i am trying to create a react native project i have 2 android devices 1 is running android 9 and 1 is running android 12 my app is getting is installing and running on device that has android 9 but my app is not running on android 12

i get the following error

```
> Task :app:installDebug
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on '2201117PI - 12' for :app:debug

> Task :app:installDebug FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: try ./gradlew -stop and rebuild project ref from -: 
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33488

Comment: accoding to that document i run the commad inside android folder i get this error  `'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. ` @sandeepsingh

Comment: Are you running in windows, then it is gradlew not ./gradlew.  on your question: Some of your node packages are using deprecated methods of the latest Gradle. You can downsize your Gradle in android/gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties

Comment: 'gradlew' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. @vijeeshin i am getting this error

Comment: @menucd are you running it in root folder, run it in android folder

Comment: @menucd My recommendation   gradlew clean then your rebuild

Comment: i tryed that but now woeking can u guid me thorugh each steps

Comment: Hey can you please share your compileSdkVersion from android > build.gradle file
For android 12 your targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion must be 31 or greater.

Comment: @Adnansayed    buildscript {
    ext {
          kotlin_version = '1.6.10' // <- add this line
        buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31


}

Comment: @Adnansayed  i have   compileSdkVersion = 31  targetSdkVersion = 31

Comment: Ok thats good. did you upgraded your gradle plugin to the latest version using  JDK11. Open your project`s android folder in AndroidStudio and check for gradle version and jdk.

Comment: @Adnansayed i am new to android studio can u walk me through the steps

Comment: i am using android studio dolphine

Comment: @Adnansayed which file should i check for  gradle version and jdk.

Comment: check your jdk version by using cmd java -version in terminal.

Comment: @Adnansayed openjdk version "11.0.17" 2022-10-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.17+8 (build 11.0.17+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.17+8 (build 11.0.17+8, mixed mode)

Comment: now see these steps from the answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66450524/11070863

Comment: @Adnansayed  i dont see   Build Tools  inside  Build, Execution, Deployment  i have added screenshot

Comment: Please check this out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67405791/gradle-tasks-are-not-showing-in-the-gradle-tool-window-in-android-studio-4-2
You also need to do some googling for yourself.

Comment: @Adnansayed  there is no option  Experimental | Do not build Gradle task list during Gradle sync.

Comment: @Adnansayed ok i found gradle but there is no option to download  JDK11 pls refer the screenshot

Answer (score -3):

In terminal, enter the `android` folder with

```
cd android
```

then run

```
.\gradlew clean
```

After that your app should run.

Comment: > Task :app:installDebug FAILED                                                                                                                               
w: Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build\kotlin\sessions

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

Comment: i am getiing foloowing error now

Comment: try this: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33488#issuecomment-1077887590

Comment: still getting this error

Comment: > Task :app:installDebug FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.